# Generating function of Poisson random variable of random parameter Poisson distributed

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

Consider the random variable $X \sim poisson(\lambda)$ where $\lambda > 0$ and $Y \sim poisson(X)$.

How can I calculate the generating function of $Y$ which determines the distribution of $Y$ uniquely?

A hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: First compute $E(s^Y\mid X)$, then $E(s^Y)=E(E(s^Y\mid X))$. (Be aware though that you will need to extend slightly the usual definition of Poisson distributions by stating that a Poisson random variable $Y_0$ with parameter $0$ is such that $P(Y_0=0)=1$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$R_{X}(t) = E(t^X) = e^{\lambda(t-1)}$$

$$M_{X}(t) = e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$$

$$R_{Y}(t) = E(t^{Y}) = E(E(t^{Y}|X)) = E(e^{X(t-1)}) = M_X(t-1) = e^{\lambda(e^{t-1}-1)}$$

$R$ is the generating function and $M$ is the moment generating function. Also note the caution mentioned in the comment by @Did.